# Can I add screen-reader-friendly tags to HTML5 Adobe Animate documents?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, accessibility, nvda

I'd like to be able to publish interactive Adobe Animate assets (written in HTML5 mode) so that screen readers like NVDA can read out the onscreen text and any "alt-like" tags I add to elements.

Has anyone had any success doing this? Can you give me some ideas how to do it?

I've had a bit of a look at ZimJS but not found any specific accessibility examples for Adobe Animate.

Thank you

As requested, here's the kind of code I'm working with, within Adobe Animate:

```
var timeline = this;
//answerBox is a instance of a symbol in Adobe Animate, and answerBoxDynamicText is a dynamic text instance within the symbol. 
timeline.answerBox.answerBoxDynamicText.text = "Text that I want screen readers to read out";
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Done - not very informative, but my question is a general one about technique, rather than applying to a specific line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out some more, so I'm answering my own question: [ZIM.JS](https://zimjs.com) may be a solution. The "ZIM Shim" and a .FLA example can be downloaded from https://zimjs.com/animate.
ZIM Shim is a library that is loaded into Adobe Animate's Publish Settings.  You can then programme accessible elements using the ZIM language from within Animate(HTML5) projects, or you might be able to convert Animate MovieClips using zimify().
The ZIM accessibility docs are here: https://zimjs.com/docs.html?item=Accessibility. Add var accessibility = new Accessibility("string"); to the top of the .FLA example and when you publish, it places HTML tags and aria-labels behind the canvas that screen readers can read out when tab through the elements.
I noticed that I had some keyboard control of the slider element too. I've only tested with NVDA, but it was quite something to go beyond "graphic object, clickable" to actually having descriptions of elements within the  read out!
I'm still trying to find out whether text can be made readable by plugins like ReadAloud too, to support people who can see but can't read the screen text.
Thanks to the people on the Zim Slack group for providing this information.

Answer (score 0):

Since Animate is essentially the descendant of Flash, it's support for accessibility will be pretty limited, but there are some things you can do.

Adobe has some [documentation on creating accessible content with Animate](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-accessible-content.html), that outlines what can be done and how to do it.

> The Animate Accessibility panel (Window > Other Panels > Accessibility) lets you provide accessibility information to screen readers and set accessibility options for individual Animate objects or entire Animate applications.

There's also some [accessibility information here](https://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flash/animation.html) that relates to the accessibility of animations in general.

If your animations aren't critical to visitors understanding the meaning of the page, then I would strongly consider hiding them altogether from screen-readers.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Unfortunately I keep hitting the Catch-22 problem that Animate's accessibility capabilities are only available in ActionScript projects. Unless I'm missing something, ActionScript projects can't be published as HTML Canvas and so won't work in modern browsers.

Comment: If you have content that can't be made accessible, and it's critical to the visitor's understanding of the page, then the typical route is usually to add a text-only equivalent. The text-only equivalent can be made available only to screen readers (using CSS), and the animation can be hidden from screen readers using the `aria-hidden` attribute on the containing element.